# Fixed div fixes the entire site

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div stick to the top of the page using the 'position:fixed;' option but when i do that, it fixes the entire site to not scroll.

Here is the css and the header.php

https://gist.github.com/mihadaiko/7237553

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't close .top-inner.

Comment: OMG Now i feel so bad for wasting space on this site, I looked that over and I thought I had all divs closed.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Close top-inner and it should work fine. Like this:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="top-inner">
    <div class="toplogin">
    <div class="register">REGISTER/LOGIN</div> <!--end of register-->
    </div> <!--end of top login-->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div id="name">MICHELLE WILLIAMS</div><!--end of name-->
        <div id="nav"> 
            <div class="nav-wrap">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container_class' => 'nav' ) ); ?>
            </div> <!--end of nav-wrap-->
        </div><!--end of nav-->
    </div><!--end menu-->
    </div><!--end of top-inner-->
</div><!--end top-->
```